# the package tsDyn NNET function

Tags: r, nnet

I am a new beginner in R, recently, I use the NNET function in the package of tsDyn, when I load two packages `tidyquant` and `tsDyn` simultaneously, there is a mistake when I just run the the code of examples in the package `tsDyn`. I don't how to solve this problem.

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tsDyn)
mod.nnet <- nnetTs(log(lynx), m=2, size=3)
mod.nnet
```

> Error: `x` must be a vector, not a ts object, do you want `stats::lag()`?

Comment: Not reproducible, works with me with no errors. Maybe this is an error that only occurs in older versions of the package, try reinstalling package `tsDyn`. The current version is `tsDyn_0.9-46`. I have voted to close as off-topic (not reproducible).

Comment: thanks,I try to reinstall package `tsDyn` and then it works with no errors. I will close the question.

Comment: when I load two packages `tidyquant` and `tsDyn` simultaneously, then the mistake happen again, I guess the two packages may be incompatible with each other? How can I solve this question? Thanks!

Comment: You are right, it seems that there is a conflict with the two packages. I have retracted my close vote. I have tried to coerce `lynx` to a vector of class `numeric` but the error still occurs, `nnetTs(log(as.numeric(lynx)), etc)`.